# Move a set of Azure resources from one subscription to another

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have created a Powershell script that allows me to move resources in a DEV subscription to a resource group in a PROD subscription.

When I run the script: it runs and runs but does not stop so I stop the execution however when I look in Azure my resources have been moved.

Do you know how I can fix the problem ?

Here is the script

```
$resources = Get-AzResource -Name * -ResourceGroupName "Name"
Move-AzResource -DestinationResourceGroupName "Test" -DestinationSubscriptionId "ID" -ResourceId $resources.Id -Force
```

I looked in the Azure documentation but couldn't find anything :
Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/move-azresource?view=azps-9.4.0

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could see the same but after sometime I see it is getting stopped.

> The lock can last for a maximum of four hours, but most moves complete in much less time.

It is just that the source and destination are getting locked during the move operation for a certain period of time depending upon the type of the resource. You can refer this [MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#:%7E:text=Both%20the%20source,much%20less%20time.).

During execution:
[image]

After execution:
[image]

As the `Move-AzResource` command returns a Boolean value to know if the transfer has completed you can include in an if else condition having `Write-Output` with related message in it.